# Is there any crossplatform small\portable C image editing library?

Tags: c, image, editing

Is there any crossplatform small\portable C image editing library?

Comment: What sort of features are you looking for? 
-file formats
-transforms
-etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IM](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/im/) library is cross platform and supports a very wide array of operations on images out of the box. It can also be extended. Its close relative [CD](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/cd/) is also occasionally useful for creating text and line art to annotate an image. Both are readily scripted from [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is cross-platform and may meet your needs.

Depending upon the image formats you need to support, you can look into libraries such as [libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg).

Comment: Or the fork of ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick (it's meant to have a stable API which IM didn't used to have, even remotely)

Answer (score 0):

check out [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php), its cross playform and has APIs for C and C++